# Flash - Change the CDATA end character?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, cdata

Since I want to store raw binary streams in CDATA Sections of XML files, the 3 character CDEnd code might mistakenly match my binary.

Any way to change the CDEnd code for Flash? I'd like it 10 char just for reliability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Maybe [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode the binary instead?

Comment: Yeah, thought as much! Its asking too much from the Flash Platform.

Comment: Actually, it's got nothing to do with flash, it's pure XML syntax.